# PHP email works on 'pass' but not on 'fail'

Tags: php

this is not my code and I have minimal php knowledge.

When I submit the form, the email and url get saved into the database and the user sees whether they 'pass' or 'fail' the test.

When the user passes, I receive an email letting me know someone took the test and passed. Everything works.

But when the user fails. Something breaks, and I don't receive any email.

```
@init();  
if(isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['url'])){
    $em = $_POST['email'];
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    if(strpos($url, "://")!==false){
        $url2 = $url;
    }else{
        $url2 = "http://".$url;
    }
    $dburl = @$db->real_escape_string($url2);
    $dbem = @$db->real_escape_string($em);
    @$db->query("INSERT INTO mobilefriendly VALUES(0, '$dbem', '$dburl')");
    $get = httpGet("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?url=".$url2);
    $data = json_decode($get);
    if($data) $ismobile = $data->ruleGroups->USABILITY->pass;
    else $ismobile=0;
    if($ismobile){
        $resp = $conf['answer1'];
    }else{
        $resp = $conf['answer2'];
    }
    echo $resp;
    $to = $conf['email'];
    $subject = "New Client";
    $message = "<html><head><title>New Client</title></head><body><p>
    The visitor with email <b>".htmlentities($em)."</b> tested the website     <a href='".htmlentities($url2)."'>".htmlentities($url2)."</a>.<br>
His website is <b>".($ismobile?'Mobile Friendly':'NOT Mobile Friendly')."    </b>.
    </p></body></html>";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
//    $headers .= 'From: <'.$conf['email'].'>' . "\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
 ?>
```

Comment: which part of the above code decides whether the user passed or failed the test??

Comment: I believe it's within the json data that gets returned by Google?

Comment: Removing all the "@"s didn't work (still sends on a 'pass', but not on 'fail')